# Discord.py how to have my bot show an activity without the "Playing"

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I'm making a discord.py bot, and I want to make a custom status. My code is:

```py
workingstate = discord.Game( "Off sorting books" )
idlestate = discord.Game( "At the front desk" )
```

But when I check the bot, it show the status as:

"Playing **At the front desk**" or "Playing **Off sorting books**"

I tried:

```py
workingstate = discord.Game(
    type=discord.ActivityType(-1),
    name="nothing, off sorting books" )

idlestate = discord.Game(
    type=discord.ActivityType(-1),
    name="at the front desk" )
```

But it doesn't show any status anymore.

How can I make my status simply "**At the front desk**"?

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is currently not possible as that endpoint (Custom Status) was not made available to bots, only normal users. Sorry :/

If you want to read more about this, here is a reddit post about your issue.
https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/dm47sv/at_least_something_regarding_custom_status/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x
(Also, please look around google before asking, I remember wondering the same thing as you a few weeks back and found this reddit answer very easily... :/ )